# MPC in simulink for reference tracking

Tags: reference, simulink, tracking, mpc

I have written a matlab code for tracking using mpc. how can i implement that on simulink? I dont want to use any custom block of mpc, so kindly help me by providing a simple example (specifically for tracking) because i also have implemented a regulator based mpc for inverted pendulum in simulink now i am confused how to make a  "reference tracking" mpc in simulink.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and include what you have tried and where you have looked for help.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Comment: First of all , my apologies for not asking the question proper (as i am new to this forum) so please pardon me ..

Comment: Secondly Respected,,,I am not facing error actually i am getting confused that how can i make "reference tracking " in simulink using Model predictive control,If some one share some example of implementing mpc in simulink I will be highly obliged.
(Regulator design has been implemented by me just got confuse to implement reference tracking in simulink (using quadprog) ).Any prestigious seniors please help me.
Thanks in advance